# Adding an image depending on the calculation

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to figure this out all day, as I would like to add an image depending on the outcome of the calculation. I am creating a BMI calculator. I have it working perfectly in Android studio. Just would like to add a skinny image if an outcome is a skinny or fat image if it says overweight. here is the code. thank you.

```
package ie.wit.fitnessmadeeasy;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BmiActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bmi);

    final Button calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc);
    final EditText weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);
    final EditText height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height);
    final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);





    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            String heightStr = height.getText().toString();
            String weightStr = weight.getText().toString();

            if (heightStr != null && !"".equals(heightStr)
                && weightStr != null  &&  !"".equals(weightStr)) {
                float heightValue = Float.parseFloat(heightStr) / 100;
                float weightValue = Float.parseFloat(weightStr);

                float bmi = weightValue / (heightValue * heightValue);



                String bmiLabel = "";

                if (bmi <= 15) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.very_very_skinny);
                } else if (bmi > 15 && bmi <= 16) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.very_skinny);
                } else if (bmi > 15 && bmi <= 18.5) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.skinny);
                } else if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi <= 25) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.normal);
                } else if (bmi > 25 && bmi <= 30) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.overweight);
                } else if (bmi > 30 && bmi <= 35) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.obese_series_i);
                } else if (bmi > 35 && bmi <= 40) {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.obese_series_ii);
                } else {
                    bmiLabel = getString(R.string.obese_series_iii);
                }

                bmiLabel = bmi + "\n\n" + bmiLabel;
                result.setText(bmiLabel);
            }


        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: Explain your problem, what did you have tried, and what didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's just out of the good ol' Android handbook.

You will need:

- ImageView
- 2 drawables in your drawable folder, one skinny, one fat

  ```
  final ImageView imageViewBMI = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_bmi);
  ```

Then somewhere inside your if/else

```
imageViewBMI.setImageResource(R.drawable.skinny);
```

Comment: Thanks so much i'll try that now